# Condion variable in addition with a semaphore, what comes first and when?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, semaphore

I want to write a program that produces a message and wait till it consumed and get read by X threads.

Only then, it will produce a new message and wait again until its read by all the consumers threads.

I know there are plenty of ways to do that, by the way I want it (in order to practice) is to do it with only 1 mutex, 1 semaphore and 1 condition variable.

I want to use the semaphore here in order to block the consumers from consuming before message is ready.

I want to use the mutex in order to guard the condition variable checking.

and I want to use the condition variable in order to maintain status and not to produce a new message till all the consumers read it the last one.

Well, this is my producer function.
I'm doing `sem_post` 3 times because there are 3 consumers in my program.

My idea was to:

**For Producer:**

```
 Write a message
    
    wait for signal and when received - check the variable of
 "how many consumers read the message" counter that should be incremented by each consumer when its done consuming.
    
    if the counter shows that every consumer is done - continue to produce a new message.
    Guard this wait with a mutex.
```

**For Consumer:**

```
Check if im allowed to consume - ask semaphore
if not - wait

if yes -
consume
increment global counter of "how many consumers read the message"
send signal that im done
```

This is my producer code:

```
void *Producer(void *unused)
{   
    while (1)
    {
        /* PRODUCE  */
        message = rand () % 100;
                
        sem_post(&sem_ready_to_read);
        sem_post(&sem_ready_to_read);
        sem_post(&sem_ready_to_read);
        
        /*  lock mutex - critical section entrance  */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&guard_cv);
        
        /*---------------------CRITICAL-SECTION-START-----------------*/
        
        while (3 != counter)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_all_read, &guard_cv);
        }
        
        /*----------------------CRITICAL-SECTION-END------------------*/
        
        /*  unlock mutex - critical section exit    */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&guard_cv);
        
    /*  end of while    */
    }
    
    return (NULL);
    
/*  end function    */
}
```

I'm stuck here because I can't figure out how to correctly use here the semaphore. I mean I have only one POSIX semaphore so I can't really set value of it other than decrement and increment by one.

So I have no idea how to deny access for all 3 consumers and then allow them at one time to enter and read together.

I don't really plan on putting a mutex in the consumer function because they only READ which doesn't really mess each others work. I just need to somehow put this semaphore as a gatekeeper.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the number of consumers known or can it vary?

Comment: @kiner_shah is known and well defined as an `enum` or a `define` at the beginning of the code